# Cascading Text box not working correctly in MVC4?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have four fields in my view: `CustomerName`, `ContactPerson`, `Email`, `MobileNo`

`CustomerName` and `ContactPerson` are Cascading Dropdown, and `Email` and `MobileNo` are textboxes.

If I select the `CustomerName`, related `ContactPerson` will load automatically in `ContactPerson` dropdown.

If I select the `Contactperson` the related `Email` and `PhoneNo` will load automatically in `Email` and `PhoneNo` textbox.  This works as expected.

If I select the `CustomerName` as `"KPM Processing Limited"` it loads the `ContactPerson` (`"Mr.Martin"`) in contact person textbox which is related to `CustomerName("KPM Processing Limited")`, and if I select the contact person name (`Mr.Martin`) the contact person related email (`kpm@example.com`) and phone number (`123456`) will automatically load in Email and PhoneNo textbox.

Now I select another `customerName` (e.g. `"N.S colors"`) after selecting (`"KPM Processing Limited"`) and select the contact person name related to "N.S Colors" (`"MR.Luthar"`). Now Mr.Luthar has mail Id but didn't have phone no so the value of phone no will be null, but it shows the output as Email=`luthar24@example.com` and phone no =`123456`.

In other words, when a contact with null phone number is selected, the displayed phone number doesn't become blank as it should.

#### My Controller Code:

```
  public JsonResult GetCustomers()
 {
    return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }

    public JsonResult GetContactPersobByCustomerId(string customerId)
   {
    Guid Id = Guid.Parse(customerId);
    var customercontacts = (from a in db.CustomerContacts where a.CustomerID == Id select a);
    return Json(customercontacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   } 

    public JsonResult GetEmailByContactPersonID(Guid CustomerContactId)
   {
  var ContactID = db.CustomerContacts.Where(i => i.CustomerContactID == CustomerContactId).Select(i => i.ContactID).FirstOrDefault();
  var contact1 = (from p in db.Contacts where p.ContactID == ContactID select p).FirstOrDefault().Email1;
    if (contact1 == null)
    {
        var contact2 = (from a in db.Contacts where a.ContactID == ContactID select a).FirstOrDefault().Email2;
        contact1 = contact2;
    }
    return Json(contact1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }

  public JsonResult GetPhoneNoByContactPersonID(Guid CustomerContactId)
{
    var ContactID = db.CustomerContacts.Where(i => i.CustomerContactID == CustomerContactId).Select(i => i.ContactID).FirstOrDefault();
    var mobile1 = (from pn in db.Contacts where pn.ContactID == ContactID select pn).FirstOrDefault().Mobile1;
    if (mobile1 == null)
    {
        var mobile2 = (from a in db.Contacts where a.ContactID == ContactID select a).FirstOrDefault().Mobile2;

        mobile1 = mobile2;
    }
    return Json( mobile1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

#### View Code:

```
 @Html.Label("Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new {     @class = "form-control required", type = "text" })

 @Html.Label("Contact Person", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerContactID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "CustomerContactID" })

 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text",disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly"  })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo)

 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" ,disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
```

#### Jquery Code

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function () {
  $.ajax(
    '@Url.Action("GetCustomers", "VisitorsForm")',{
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "Json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#CustomerID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerID + '">' + value.DisplayName + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });

  $('#CustomerID').change(function () {
   $('#CustomerContactID').empty();
    $.ajax(
       '@Url.Action("GetContactPersobByCustomerId", "VisitorsForm")',{
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "Json",
            data: { CustomerID: $('#CustomerID').val() },
            success: function (data) {
        $('#CustomerContactID').append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
             $('#CustomerContactID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerContactID + '">' + value.ContactReference + '</option>');
               });
              }
           });
        });
    });

   $("#CustomerContactID").change(function () {
       alert("hhh");
    $.ajax(
    '@Url.Action("GetEmailByContactPersonID", "VisitorsForm")',{
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: { CustomerContactID: $("#CustomerContactID").val()
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve Email.' + ex);
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#Email").val(data);
                         }
                     });
                 });

  $("#CustomerContactID").change(function () {
   alert("hhh");
  $.ajax(
    '@Url.Action("GetPhoneNoByContactPersonID", "VisitorsForm")',{
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: { CustomerContactID: $("#CustomerContactID").val()
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve Email.' + ex);
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data) {

            $("#MobileNo").val(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

How can I make the phone field blank when the phone number is null?

Comment: As per you last question, do not have 2 separate ajax calls to 2 separate methods. Make one call to one method that return an anonymous object containing both values. And you controllers are throwing exceptions which is why the values will not be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem is when change to a customer who has no phone no, the
MobileNo read only textbox value will not clear.

If my understanding is correct, then your problem lies in your Action GetPhoneNoByContactPersonID()

specificaly, when you are getting mobile1 - the linq query you used was FirstOrDefault().Mobile1,
if it can not be find, null will be returned, and calling Mobile1 in null will result excpetion, resulting nothing pass back from ajax.

hence change your action to something like:

```
public JsonResult GetPhoneNoByContactPersonID(Guid CustomerContactId)
{
    var resultMobileNumber = string.Empty;

    var ContactID = db.CustomerContacts.Where(i => i.CustomerContactID == CustomerContactId).Select(i => i.ContactID).FirstOrDefault();
    if(ContactID != null)
    {
    var contact = (from pn in db.Contacts where pn.ContactID == ContactID select pn).FirstOrDefault();
    // check if contact is found
        if (contact != null)
    {
        // if mobile 1 has value
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Mobile1) == false)
        {
            resultMobileNumber  = contact.Mobile1;
        }
        else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Mobile2) == false)
        {
            resultMobileNumber  = contact.Mobile2;
        }
    }
    }

    return Json(resultMobileNumber, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```